# Using Dirty Rects in Pygame updates the entire display, not just the rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm a pretty new programmer, and recently I've been trying to use Dirty Rects to make my game run faster. Unfortunately, I've run into some issues. No matter how I pass the rect, it will always update the whole screen. I have tried entering the Rect parameters directly into the update(), creating a pygame.Rect object, and using get_rect() on an image (not all pictured below).

```
self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
self.screen.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
self.screen.blit(self.image, (200, 200))
self.update = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 1, 1))
 
pygame.display.update(self.update)
```

here are some of the other methods:

```
pygame.display.update(self.image.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0)))
pygame.display.update((0, 0, 1, 1))
```

One of two things will happen. If I set the Rect to have width and height 0, then nothing on the screen will update. Otherwise, everything will update, regardless of the parameters. I've heard some issues regarding this when using OS, but I use Windows 10 and Python 3.9, here is the code on a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DqEWHZKh Thanks for the help!

Note: The pasted code is just a test program I made to try some stuff out, not my actual game.

Edit: Updating my Pygame to 2.0.1 worked to solve the issue, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce the issue (Windows 10, Python 3.9.1, Pygame 2.0.1). What is your IDE? Do you use an `pygame.OPENGL` display?

Comment: I use WingIDE, and I'm not sure what pygame.OPENGL is so I'll assume I do not.

Comment: Update to pygame 2.0.1 if you're not there already. This is a known issue for windows / pygame 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in PyGame version 2.0.0:

[pygame.display.update(Rect) updates the whole screen on Windows due to SDL2 UpdateWindowFramebuffer implementation #251](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/251).

The error has been resolved. You have to update to  PyGame version 2.0.1